# Best way to add shaking recognition to your app (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, toast, android-sensors

My english isn't very well - so I'm sorry if my question sounds a little bit confusing ;)

I've made an activity for recognizing strong movements. If I start the activity as a single activity in an application it does work. But now, i want to add the activity to an other app. I've tried to start the activity as a second activity with an intent. It seems not to be possible to run both activities at the same time!? I don't want to copy the features of the second activity to my main activity - to keep the main activity clean and the features capsuled. Please tell me the best way to add my features (movement recognition with a toast) to my application.

So ...this is the code i want to change from an activity to ...whateverItShouldBe ...

```
public class SensorActivity extends Activity
    implements SensorEventListener{

//static SensorActivity sensorActivity;

// ToDo: test and ACCELMAX for Smartphones and Glasses
// Glasses should have a lower value
private static final int ACCELMAX = 15;

private SensorManager sensorMan;
private Sensor accelerometer;

private float[] mGravity;
private float mAccel;
private float mAccelCurrent;
private float mAccelLast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //sensorActivity = this;

    sensorMan=(SensorManager)

            getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    accelerometer=sensorMan.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccel=0.00f;
    mAccelCurrent=SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
    mAccelLast=SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
}

// for closing activity in an other activity
/*
public static SensorActivity getInstance(){
    return sensorActivity;
}*/

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorMan.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorMan.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        mGravity = event.values.clone();
        // Shake detection
        float x = mGravity[0];
        float y = mGravity[1];
        float z = mGravity[2];
        mAccelLast = mAccelCurrent;
        mAccelCurrent = (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
        float delta = mAccelCurrent - mAccelLast;
        mAccel = mAccel * 0.9f + delta;
        if (mAccel > ACCELMAX) {

            // custom toast warning
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.warning_toast, null);

            ImageView imgToast = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastImage);
            //imgToast.setImageResource(R.drawable.dontrun);

            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
            text.setText("");   // the warning is in the background, so we don't need text atm

            Toast dontRunToast = Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            dontRunToast.setView(layout);
            dontRunToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            dontRunToast.show();
        }
    }

}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // required method
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can't run two activities in the same time as you can see in [this life sycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BQve.png)

I think that you will have to copy these mathodes to the main activity in order to use them.
To keep your activity neat and organised you can use (works with android studio, i don't now about eclipse

```
//region *title*

*write your methode here*

//endregion
```

these comments will let you close and minimaze the code between them
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNjdA.png)

Comment: Thx. It's a nice trick I didn't know. But it's not a solution for keeping it modular.

Comment: you can also write a regular class that will implemant the SensorEventListener and to give it a the LatoutInflator and the Context  as argument in the constractor of the class I think that this should also work